# free up not used space on a qcow2-image-file on kvm/qemu

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, disk-image, qcow2

we are using kvm/qemu with qcow2-images for our virtual machines.

qcow2 has this nice feature where the image file only allocates the actually needed space by the virtual-machine. but how do i shrink back the image file, if the virtual machine's allocated space gets smaller?

example:

1.) i create a new image with qcow2 format, size 100GB

2.) i use this image to install ubuntu. installation needs about 10 gb, the image-file grows up to about 10GB. nothing unexpected so far.

3.) i fill up the image with about 40 GB of additional data. the image-file grows up to 50GB. i am ok with that :-)

4.) this is where it gets strange: i delete all of the 40GB data on the image, but the image-size still eats up 50GB.

question: how do i free up that 40GB of data and shrink the image to the only needed 10 GB?

thanks in advance,
berni

Answer (score 22, accepted):

virt-sparsify can do all this with less hassle on your part:
http://libguestfs.org/virt-sparsify.1.html

Comment: @dyasny If the existing answers to old questions have become obsolete over time, it is worth writing a new answer. This particular new answer might however not be up to standards for this site.

Comment: @dyasny If somebody want to spend the effort on writing a new quality answer, each time the old one is obsolete, they should be encouraged to do so. A more thorough discussion on how to deal with outdated answers is better suited for meta.

Answer (score 33):

The image will not shrink automatically, since when you delete files, you don't actually delete data (this is why undelete works). Qemu has a facility to shrink qcow2 images back, but what the utility does is really deduplicate the zeroes from the disk, leaving all other information intact. So the idea would be to:

1. Zero-fill the drive (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/some/file` until you run out of space)
2. delete /some/file
3. shut down the VM
4. cd to where the images for the VM are kept and run `qemu-img convert -O qcow2 original_image.qcow2 deduplicated_image.qcow2`
5. change the VM settings to use the new deduplicated_image.qcow2, test the VM is working, and remove the old image

This, afaik, will only work with qcow2 images, I haven't tested other formats.

Comment: If you have a windows guest run [SDelete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sdelete.aspx) -z to zero up all free space (steps 1,2 above)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the accepted answer (which describe the more common, general method to shrink a qcow2 file), modern versions (ie: RHEL7+) of the libvirt/qemu/qcow2 stack provide the `virtio-scsi` driver which supports the `discard='unmap'` option.

If the virtual machine uses `virtio-scsi` and the libvirt definition include `discard='unmap'`, a simple `fstrim` on the guest filesystem will release assigned-but-unused free space on the host. This can be checked with `du -hs <guestdisk>` on host side (note: `ls -al <guestdisk>` will *not* show the real allocated size, just the logical one).

*Note: qemu 4.x added `discard` support for `virtio-blk` too, removing the needing for `virtio-scsi` for trim to work.*

On newer libvirt/qemu instances (ie: RHEL8+), when using `virtio-scsi`, guest file size can be reduced even if the guest OS does not support trim: by enabling *both* `discard='unmap'` and `discard_zeroes='unmap'` writing a sequential stream of zero on guest side (ie: via `dd if=/dev/zero of=/zero.img bs=1M count=1024`) will trigger host-size trimming of the affected LBA ranges. However, please note that this can be CPU-intensive for the host (which had to "parse" any guest write searching for repeating zeroes), so it should be only enabled in specific cases.

Both methods will reduce the *physical* allocated size (what `du -hs` shows). For reducing the logical size (what a simple `ls -al` gives) you need to use `virt-spasify` or `qemu-img` (as described in the other answers).

Comment: Correct syntax in libvirt is `<driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' discard='unmap' detect_zeroes='unmap'/>`

Comment: virtio_blk now supports discard as of host qemu 4.0 and more recent guest linux kernels.

Comment: @gps true, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [virt-sparsify](http://libguestfs.org/virt-sparsify.1.html) for this. It automatically zeros and sparsifies free space on most filesystems it finds within the source disk image (supports ext2/3/4, btrfs, NTFS, etc) .

**Step-by-step instructions for in-place conversion**

1. Shut down the VM
2. Keep a backup
3. Convert: `virt-sparsify --in-place disk.img`

**Step-by-step instructions for conversion to another file** (this is safer but requires more free space):

1. Shut down the VM
2. Convert: `virt-sparsify disk.img new-file.img`
3. Swap old with new image file: `mv disk.img disk.img.bak && mv new-file.img disk.img`
4. If VM starts normally you can remove the backup: `rm disk.img.bak`

P.S.: You can also convert between formats when you use virt-sparsify:

```
virt-sparsify disk.raw --convert qcow2 disk.qcow2
```

Comment: dyasny's answer is complete, Blake's answer is up-to-date but I want the best of them :-)

Comment: `virt-sparsify --in-place disk.qcow2` didn't reduce the file size for me. `virt-sparsify disk.qcow2 disk2.qcow2` did.

Answer (score 1):

`virt-sparsify --compress fileA fileB` will reduce the size of the image, however it creates the qcow2 image as another file, so you will have to rename and move things around. You cannot use `--compress` and `--in-place` at the same time. 
See the following link to learn more. http://libguestfs.org/virt-sparsify.1.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers about `virt-sparsify`:

**Temporary Folder**

virt-sparsify uses your /tmp folder to create/manipulate the new disk image before place it in destination folder. So, your / partition should have free space even if your volume file is in other partition.

If you don't have enouth space, you can set a new temp folder with `--tmp my_tmp_folder` option.
Example:

```
mkdir my_tmp_folder
virt-sparsify \
  --tmp my_tmp_folder \
  ubuntu.qcow2 new_ubuntu.qcow2
```

- This will not work with `--in-place`;
- You can remove the tmp folder after the process is complete.

**Verbose**

There is an verbose option to help you see what's going on.
Example:

```
virt-sparsify \
  -v \
  ubuntu.qcow2 new_ubuntu.qcow2
```

**Check before delete**

As said before, always boot your vm and check if everything is working before delete the original disk image.

Comment: after shrinking compressed qcow2 --in-place gives read error when used qemu-img convert. Be mindful of this.